# push my local folder project to TFS

Tags: git, tfs

I ran:

```
git remote add origin <url to the tfs :https://tfs.....>
git push –f origin master
```

the result:

- first time the console gave me : fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

  - What i tried to solve it : i tried to increase the size by : git config ssl.postBuffer 524288000 (the error fatal gone but there another issue)
  - then the console take a long time without giving any result... I waited one hour without any result, it still said: `writing objects 100% done. and 
    Total 680 <delta 194>, reused 638 <delta 182>`.

Comment: What version of TFS? Is there a proxy server involved? what's your version of the Git commandline? What operating system are you on?

Comment: git : 2.10.0 , windows 8 , how can i respond on other questions? how can i know what version of TFS and is there a proxy server involved?

Comment: What is the largest file size in your local project folder? And do you use any proxy?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow [this MSDN article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/share-your-code-in-git-cmdline):

- **Create a local Git repo for your code.** (*If your code is already in a local Git repo, you can skip this step.*)

  1. Navigate to the folder where your code is on the command line:

> cd /home/fabrikam/fiber

2. Create a Git repo on your machine to store your code. You will connect this repo to Team Services in the next step.

> git init .

3. Commit your code into the local Git repo.

> git add --all
>
> git commit -m "first commit of my code"

**Create your Team Services repo**

1. Create a new Team services Git repo for your code. Copy the clone URL once you are done creating your repo.
2. Connect your local repo to the Team Services repo using the copied clone URL in the git remote command:

> git remote add origin 
>   https://fabrikops2.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam/_git/FabrikamApp

**Push your code**

Set up authentication with credential managers or SSH before continuing.

> git push origin master